# Scala bit operation

Tags: scala, byte, bit

I'm doing some research on scala bit operation as below:

```
scala> val b = 8
b: Int = 8

scala> var c:Int = b | (1<<4)
c: Int = 24

scala> var c:Int = c | (1<<5)
c: Int = 32
```

I don't understand why the result looks correct when assign value from b to c but looks incorrect when from c to itself. The expect result is 56 for the 3rd statement. Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the third line, you are redefining variable `c`. The REPL apparently works in such a way that it first creates the variable which is set to its default value `0` and then it does `0 | (1 << 5)` which is 32.

Solution: Don't redefine the variable `c`, just reassign it:

```
scala> val b = 8
b: Int = 8

scala> var c: Int = b | (1 << 4)
c: Int = 24

scala> c = c | (1 << 5)      // Don't redefine c, just reassign it
c: Int = 56
```

In a "real" program (not in the REPL) you cannot define the same variable with the same name more than once in the same scope. You'd get a compiler error if you would try to redefine the variable `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the repl you are redinfing the variable c.  So on the line

```
var c:Int = c | (1<<5)
```

It is the equivilant of

```
var c:Int = 0 | (1<<5)
```

Which is 32.  If you use a new variable like d then you get 56 as you would expect.